# Where are the Office PIA's installed?

Tags: iis, office-automation

I am writing an application in IIS that uses the Microsoft office excel automation library. I have downloaded the Office PIA from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508) and it downloaded an executable called PIARedist which I ran. This unpacked into 3 files o20120_eula.txt, o2012_readme.rtf and o2012pia which is a windows installer package. I ran the windows installer package, and that's where I got stuck, I expected it to unpack all of the libraries that I need, or put them somewhere in the file system, but nothing. The installer ran, but with no indication of what it was doing or what it was installing. Where do I go from here to obtain these libraries? And is developing on windows always this awful?

Answer (score 1):

They live here:

> C:\Program Files x86\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I go from here to obtain these libraries?

They will have been installed in the GAC.  After installing, you should be able to add a COM reference to Excel in Visual Studio, and it will reference the PIA assembly rather than generating an assembly with TLBIMP.

And applications that reference the PIA from that version of Office will be able to run.

> And is developing on windows always this awful?

Not always, but more often than I'd like.

Comment: Any idea where in the file system that is? I'm using IIS so I have to add external libraries manually, by just dragging them into a bin directory in my project.

Comment: If they're in the GAC you shouldn't need to add them to your bin directory.  Simply reference then using a strong name.  Nevertheless, on my machine the Excel Interop assembly is in C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\14.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

Comment: I'm not getting the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel directory in the C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL directory or in the C:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly directory. Both places where it's supposed to be according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx).

Comment: Is the relevant version of Office installed on the target machine?  Maybe the installer won't install the PIA assemblies if Office isn't present - without Office they wouldn't be much use.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just hadn't installed office on my machine. I assumed that it came preinstalled since there was an icon for it in the start menu, but that icon was what installed office.

Comment: This is incorrect, the PIA's are included with Visual Studio *not Office*. You obviously need Office installed to talk to it using the Interop as a shim.